# How to pass a custom tag parameter from a form field?

Tags: django, django-templates

The main thing i need to do is extend a model `DetailView` page with a specific custom python function. That function need to be called from `DetailView` page and return some data, depending on the parameter entered by user into custom form on `DetailView`. That data, responded by custom function, i need to display on the same `DetailView` page, without database record, when user enter a form field value and press 'submit'. I think to implement that function by custom tag, which is located in `/app/templatetags/func.py`

```
#/app/templatetags/func.py

from django import template
register = template.Library()

def get_data(current_version, previous_version, some_data):
    return current_version+' works!'
```

and call it in template, something like that:

```
<!--templates/detail/article_detail.html-->

{% load func %}
...
{% get_data article_object.value %}

<form action="" method="get">
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Compare">
</form>
...
```

it works then i trying to specify an argument here in template.
But i cannot understand how to take it from the form. Here is `views.py`:

```
class ArticleDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DetailView):
    model = Article
    context_object_name = 'article_object'
    template_name = 'detail/article_detail.html'
    login_url = 'login'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = GetChangelog()
        return context
```

`forms.py`

```
class GetChangelog(forms.Form):
    diff_version = forms.CharField(label='difference',max_length=10)
```

Looks like it's impossible to pass a parameter through the url, because of [that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#what-the-urlconf-searches-against). Imagine that my article detail view page has an url:
http://blog.com/articles/4 ; when i put some data to the form and press `submit` , it becomes http://blog.com/articles/4?diff_ver=4, but i find myself on the same page, while in the urls i have pointed that record:

```
#urls.py

...

path('articles/<int:pk>?diff_ver=<str:diff_ver>', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article_changelog')
```

According to my idea when url have changed to http://blog.com/articles/4?diff_ver=4, it must to redirect me into another view with some additional data from my custom function from `func.py`, which will recieve diff_ver as an argument. Or may be some another approaches are acceptable here?

**UPDATE**
it can be done easily by context, thank to @dirkgroten:

```
class ArticleDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DetailView):
    model = Article
    context_object_name = 'article_object'
    template_name = 'detail/article_detail.html'
    login_url = 'login'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context['parameter'] = self.request.GET.get('diff_version')
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = GetChangelog()
        return context
```

and in template:

```
<!--templates/detail/article_detail.html-->

{% load func %}
...
{% get_data parameter %}

<form action="" method="get">
    {{ form }}
    {{ parameter }}
    <input type="submit" value="Compare">
</form>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit a form using GET, the form parameters are appended to the URL as [**query components**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) as  you show in the example, `?diff_ver=4`. These query components are **not** part of the [**path component**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) of the URL and therefore aren't taken into account by the Django URL pattern resolution.

But like with a `POST` request, where you can get the submitted parameters with `request.POST`, they are part of the `request.GET` dictionary in your view. So `request.GET.get('diff_ver')` will return the value submitted or `None` if nothing is submitted.